# How to extract attributes from params and save it to different model in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an API POST request to Rails server to a `schedule` model. In my app, the request is being made to `api/schedule`. Schedule `has_many` workers. Inside that post request, the parameters looks something like this (copied from rails log):

```
Started POST "/api/schedules" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-25 09:57:49 -0700
Processing by SchedulesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1, "worker_info"=>{"name"=>"Hello", "phone"=>"123-456-7890"}, "sched
ule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

I want to extract the information inside `worker_info` and create a new worker object (worker has 2 attributes: name and phone). Something like this:

```
  //schedule controller
  def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    @worker = Worker.new(worker_params) #get the parameters
    @worker.save #save the newly created worker object
    if @schedule.save
      render json: @schedule
    else
      render json: @schedule, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

...


  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :user_id, :worker_info)
  end

  def worker_params
    params.permit(:worker_info)
  end
```

The request method looks like this (from React):

```
  return fetch(`api/schedules`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      date: date,
      user_id: 1,
      worker_info: {name: 'Hello', phone: '123-456-7890'}
    })
    ...
```

Right now, with the current code, it creates a new schedule and a worker with `nil` name and `nil` phone.

How can I make a request to `api/schedules` with the given parameters and have Rails to extract `worker_info`, grab `name` and `phone`, and save it to `Worker` model?

*I am aware that Rails have something called `accept_nested_attributes_for`, but I have had many complications and I prefer to do it manually. How can do this manually?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using updating `worker_params` like this:

```
def worker_params
  params.require(:worker_info).permit(:name, :phone)
end
```

---

Also notice that `worker_info` and `schedule` are at the same level, that is, `worker_info` is not a key of `schedule`. So you could remove `worker_info` from `schedule_params`:

```
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :user_id)
end
```

For easy reading, use this is a view of your parameters (in *pretty* format):

```
{
  "date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z",
  "user_id"=>1,
  "worker_info"=> {
    "name"=>"Hello",
    "phone"=>"123-456-7890"
  },
  "schedule"=> {
    "date"=>"2017-05-26T02:00:00.000Z",
    "user_id"=>1
  }
}
```

Comment: @Iggy You can read more about _Strong Parameters_ [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), that will give you a better understanding of `require` and `permit`. Regarding "How does schedule show up as an object" i couldn't tell, i'll need to see more of your code.